# WooCommerce use custom price when placing order

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have setup a local Wordpress environment with WooCommerce. The goal is a buy-one-get-one of equal or lesser value scenario.

I have the cart displaying a single item per line. I have isolated the cart products by 'key' not 'product_id' which is necessary for the equal or lesser portion of the requirements. I have created an array of necessary 'key' and am matching that against the cart contents by 'key'. If the keys match, `'set_price('0.00');'`

This works on the cart page and checkout page. It all works beautifully until I process the order (currently using COD option only). Then all of the prices reset to the regular price as it appears on the product page (the "regular price"). So the orders do not reflect the actual cost.

Below is the code I have:

```
function resetPrice( $cart_obj ) {

global $allFreeItems; //all items in cart (and relevant data) that need to be free

$comparison_ids = array(); //isolate keys for comparison

foreach ($allFreeItems as $key => $value) {
    $comparison_ids[] = $allFreeItems[$key][1]; //get unique key for each line item
}


foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    // The corresponding product key of line item
    $product_key = $cart_item['key'];
    // Compare value of above to array of key's and change value
    if (in_array($product_key, $comparison_ids)) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 0.00 );
    }
//        else
//       {
//           $cart_item['data']->get_price();
//       }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'resetPrice');
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'resetPrice');
```

I thought perhaps I wasn't using the correct hook, but all examples point to `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`. The only difference I see is the everyone keeps using `['product_id']` rather than how I am doing it by `[key]` Is there something that happens when I click the "place order" button that I am not seeing? Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: How do you set `$allFreeItems;` and where is the related code. Please remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"*.

Comment: LoicTheAztec - Thanks for taking a look. So it sounds like in order to change the price on the order, I have to target the product_id or variation_id, correct? The problem I have is the BOGO issue. If a person adds 2 items of "Product A" at $10 a piece and I target based on "product_id" and set_price(0.00) then the cart total will read $0 because it targets both instances because both have the same ID. I was using cart_item_key because it allows me to target individual items since the key is unique even when the product_id is the same.

Comment: Your case is complicated, and it's difficult to understand it globally without having the hands on it. You can use your way with keys (I have never use it yet), but actually with the code in your question and the provided details is not possible to give you any real help. (Last thing, to set cart item prices, I have never used `woocommerce_after_checkout_form`… in general `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` is enough)... I think that the problem is around `$allFreeItems;`…

Comment: LoicTheAztec - Thank you sir. After reviewing my code based on your suggestions, I was able to get rid of `woocommerce_after_checkout_form` and only use `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`. I am still using the 'key' in order to do the comparison, but I moved the code for generating `$allFreeItems`. I believe the problem originates from using `WC()->cart->cart_contents` instead of `$cart_obj->get_cart()` when creating the `$allFreeItems` array. I wasn't passing $cart_obj in the previous function. I'm not well versed in PHP so apologies for poor question construct, and thanks for your help.